# Magento 1 problem adding shipping price

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, quote

Been struggling with this for a week now. I have some code where I create a quote and add shipping details but I can't get the shipping price to save on the quote. Everything else such as the shipping method and description works though so I am a bit puzzled.

Here is my code

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load(1234);

$shipCode = $_GET['so-rate-code'];
$delCost = $_GET['so-rate-price'];
$delTitle = $_GET['so-rate-title'];



$quote->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod($shipCode); // WORKS FINE
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setShippingDescription($delTitle); // WORKS FINE
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setShippingAmount($delCost); // WONT SAVE !!!
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setCost($delCost); // WONT SAVE !!
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setBaseShippingAmount($delCost); // WONT SAVE !!
$quote->collectTotals();
$quote->save();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated